# What is correct aws lambda python output format to aws lex. Getting Invalid Lambda Response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

i hit a huge roadblock with aws lambda function not sending expected json format to aws lex. Building a simple weather chatbot that communicates with lambda python function. It has just one slot {city}. In Python i tried many different variations of `message` variable but all tries are getting lex error **Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled**

Here is lambda function:

```
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    city = event['currentIntent'] ['slots'] ['City']
    api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+ city +"TOKEN"
    json_data = requests.get(api).json()
    temp = int(json_data['main']['temp'] - 273.15)
    answer = f"Weather in {city} is {temp}C"
    message = {
        "dialogAction": {
            "type": "ConfirmIntent", #also tried Close
            "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
            "message": {
                "contentType": "PlainText",
                "content": answer
                }
            }
        }

    return message

#Also tried variant 2 With contentType PlainText or SSML:
    message = {
        "sessionAttributes": {},
        "dialogAction": {
            "type": "Close",
            "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
            "message": {
                "contentType": "PlainText",
                "content": answer
            }
        }
    }

#Variant 3:
message = {
    "sessionState": {
        "dialogAction": {
            "type": "Close"
        },
        "intent": {
          "name": "FindingWeather"
        },
        "state": "Fulfilled"
    },
    "messages": [
        {
            "contentType": "PlainText",
            "content": answer
        }
    ]
}
```

Neither works, one error for all tries... HELP )

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled

Answer (score 0):

I've pulled this Lambda response from one of my Cloudwatch logs.

```
{
   "dialogAction":{
      "type":"Close",
      "fulfillmentState":"Fulfilled",
      "message":{
         "contentType":"PlainText",
         "content":"MY BOTS RESPONSE"
      }
   }
}
```

I would suggest that you hardcode a sample response (using mine perhaps) and make that the only response from the Lambda function. The idea will be to test that Lex works correctly with a proven response message.

Once you have that working, add in `sessionAttributes` and then finally substitute the value of content with the value from the `answer` variable. Hopefully this will help locate the line that's causing the error.